you must update the user agent
you must update the user agent to: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Redmi Note 8 Pro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36 and then you can return to the user agent of your preference ex: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36
In this example I start using my preferred user agent, but when I identify that a url has "google.com" I change the userAgent to trick the system, because behind the scenes Google looks for the True userAgent that is being used and compares it with the userAgent that is being sent, if the real userAgent is mobile and the defined one is something else, it considers it a security flaw.
see an example with javascript
`export function Page({ route }: IPropsNavigation) {
ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT);
NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync('hidden');
const [userAgentState, setUserAgentState] = useState(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36'
);
const { url } = route.params;

function getAuthGoogle({ url }: WebViewNavigation) {
    if (url.search('google.com') !== -1) {
        setUserAgentState(
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Redmi Note 8 Pro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        );
    }
}

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[{ flex: 1 }]}>
        <WebView
            source={{ uri: url }}
            onNavigationStateChange={e => getAuthGoogle(e)}
            userAgent={userAgentState}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
            useWebView2={true}
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
        />
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
    </SafeAreaView>
);

}`

what's your question here? currently your post doesn't have any
